# How to bind S-Spacebar to work identically to spacebar?

Tags: keyboard, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

When typing in Vim I find myself slowed down significantly by the fact that <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't advance the cursor, so if I'm typing fluidly and I try to type a capital letter or symbol followed by a space, Vim thinks the shift key is still active and the cursor doesn't advance. Then I make a typo and have to backtrack.  When typing any significant amount of code this quickly becomes a significant user experience issue.  Other text editing programs treat <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> the same as <kbd>Space</kbd>, including web browsers when typing in text fields.

I don't really know how Vim works - is this happening because when I hit the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, Vim starts listening for a <kbd>Shift</kbd>-foo escape sequence?  Is there a way to remap `S-Space` to have the same functionality as the spacebar, with none of that "listening for an escape sequence" latency?

I currently have `Tab` and `S-Tab` bound to "next buffer" and "prev buffer" in my vimrc.  Can I have `S-Space` work the same as `Space`, without latency, while stil having this `S-Tab` binding, or will I have to remove all `S-foo` bindings to get rid of the listening-for-escape-sequence latency?

Comment: is this terminal vim or with a gui, if so which one?

Comment: it's terminal vim.

Comment: then this this probably means, the terminal intercepts the shift-tab and it never gets to vim.